# get back to lower level j2me

Tags: java-me, midp, lcdui

I have a textfield (lower level) a call a function that call a higher level form that contains a datafield to pick up a date and display it in my textfield lowerlevel.

The problem is I cannot get back to my textfield (lower level) since the datefield appears

```
public void formdatepicker() {


    final javax.microedition.lcdui.Command CONFIRM_COMMAND
            = new javax.microedition.lcdui.Command("OK",
            javax.microedition.lcdui.Command.OK, 1);
    javax.microedition.lcdui.Command CANCEL_COMMAND
            = new javax.microedition.lcdui.Command("Cancel",
            javax.microedition.lcdui.Command.CANCEL, 2);


    final DateField datefield = new DateField("Pick a date", DateField.DATE);
    form.append(datefield);
    form.addCommand(CONFIRM_COMMAND);
    form.addCommand(CANCEL_COMMAND);
    form.setCommandListener(new CommandListener() {                         
        public void commandAction(javax.microedition.lcdui.Command c, Displayable d) {
             if (c == CONFIRM_COMMAND) {
                Date date = datefield.getDate();
                display.setCurrent(null);// try to hide the current form to get 




             }                              
        }
    });

    Display.getInstance().getJ2MEDisplay().setCurrent(form);
```

Comment: Are you mixing LCDUI and LWUIT?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your mistake is wrong assumption about what `setCurrent(null)` does. Per your question and code snippet, it looks like you expect it to somehow show the screen that has been displayed prior to `form`. It doesn't, see the exaplanation in the API javadocs ([available online](http://docs.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/javax/microedition/lcdui/Display.html#setCurrent%28javax.microedition.lcdui.Displayable%29)):

> The application may pass null as the argument to setCurrent(). This does not have the effect of setting the current Displayable to null; instead, the current Displayable remains unchanged. However, the application management software may interpret this call as a request from the application that it is requesting to be placed into the background...

If you want to use `setCurrent(Displayable)` to show some screen instead of current one, you need to pass this screen as an argument to `setCurrent`.

---

For the sake of completeness, note that there is [another version](http://docs.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/javax/microedition/lcdui/Display.html#setCurrent%28javax.microedition.lcdui.Alert,%20javax.microedition.lcdui.Displayable%29) of `setCurrent` that accepts two parameters, first of which is `Alert`, which works a bit differently, but it is not applicable in your case because you use `Form` not `Alert`.